# Why was Paul annoyed with the loud slave girl in Acts 16?

Tags: exegesis, paul-apostle, acts, divination

In Acts 16, why was Paul annoyed with the slave girl who had a spirit of divination and kept shouting *"These men are servants of the Most High God, who proclaim to you the way of salvation."*? Isn't what she is saying the truth? Why would Paul be annoyed by it and cast out the spirit?

> **Acts 16:16-18 ESV** As we were going to the place of prayer, we were met by a slave girl who had a spirit of divination and brought her owners much gain by fortune-telling. She followed Paul and us, crying out, “These men are servants of the Most High God, who proclaim to you the way of salvation.” And this she kept doing for many days. Paul, **having become greatly annoyed**, turned and said to the spirit, “I command you in the name of Jesus Christ to come out of her.” And it came out that very hour.

Comment: Are you fishing for a reference to the messianic secret?  Personally, I think Paul was just that: annoyed at a girl constantly interrupting him.

Comment: @AffableGeek That's what I thought first as well--but it seems like such an odd thing for Luke to include and to be so specific about. I'm sure Paul was interrupted all the time--why highlight this story and what the girl said? I know these events were a catalyst for Paul's jail time but it still seems like Luke added more detail than he needed too for it to be meaningless fluff. Also, I don't get your fishing reference :|